# Remove Ads (In-App Purchase) UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I am a simple uwp app (published in Microsoft/Windows Store), and I have only an ad (banner) in my main page. I want remove the ad when user makes in-app purchase.
I have already followed tutorials from Microsoft and Microsoft Virtual Academy but I can not remove the ad!

```
private async void removeAds_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!AppLicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsOffer"].IsActive)
            {
                try
                {
                    // The customer doesn't own this feature, so 
                    // show the purchase dialog.

                    PurchaseResults results = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("RemoveAdsOffer");

                    //Check the license state to determine if the in-app purchase was successful.

                    if (results.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded)
                    {
                        removeAds.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        Ad.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // The in-app purchase was not completed because 
                    // an error occurred.
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The customer already owns this feature.
            }
}
```

I have the ad (Ad) and a button (removeAds) to remove the advertising on my main page!

The ad and button are removed but when I navigate to another page of my app or close and reopen the app, the ad reappears.

Comment: can you please give me the link to the tutorial you are following? which type of add on are you using? and which api are you using for this line "AppLicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsOffer"].IsActive" thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect? You're only processing the logic on the button click. As soon as another page is loaded, the logic is gone. You'll need to check and see if `ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsOffer"].IsActive` on every page load.

Comment: And how I do this?

Comment: Umm... Whenever the page loads just

`if(AppLicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsOffer"].IsActive)
//remove ads
`

Comment: Thank you! I will test
I only need put this code, and everthing is work?

Comment: @BrandonMiller hey if you can help me with this as well, I need to add remove ads functionality as well, I just want to knw which type of add on should I use for it and where did the "if(AppLicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsOffer"].IsActive)"  code come from? because it is not part of the official api.